# Problem on mock new Object using PowerMockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

Basically i have a class, TwsConnector, with 1 method, that provide a connection via REST call to a client that schedule a job.

This is the class:

```
@Service
public class TwsConnector {

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwsConnector.class);

    public void addSchedulingOnTws(TwsRequest record) throws ApiException {
        
        ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
        client.setBasePath(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiUrl());
        client.setUsername(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiUsername());
        client.setPassword(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiPassword());

        PlanApi plan = new PlanApi(client);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getYear(), 
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getMonthValue(),
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getDayOfMonth(),
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getHour(),
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getMinute(),
                record.getTsOperation().toLocalDateTime().getSecond(),
                0,
                ZoneOffset.UTC
                );

        SubmitZOSJobStreamInfo submitJobStreamInfo = new SubmitZOSJobStreamInfo();
        submitJobStreamInfo.setName(record.getJobStreamName());
        submitJobStreamInfo.setStartTime(offsetDateTime);
        submitJobStreamInfo.setPriority(5);
        submitJobStreamInfo.setHoldAll(false);

        QueryFilterPlan body = new QueryFilterPlan();
        FiltersPlan filters = new FiltersPlan();
        JobStreamInPlanFilter jobStreamInPlanFilter = new JobStreamInPlanFilter();
        jobStreamInPlanFilter.setJobStreamName(record.getJobStreamName());
        filters.setJobStreamInPlanFilter(jobStreamInPlanFilter);
        body.setFilters(filters);
        logger.info("Searching on TWS JobStream:");
        logger.info("Searching Param [Name]: [" + record.getJobStreamName() + "]");
        logger.info("Searching Param [Timestamp]: [" + offsetDateTime.toString() + "]");
        logger.info("Searching Param [Engine]: [" + propertiesConfig.getTwsApiEngine() + "]");
        List<JobStreamInPlan> jobStreamInPlanList = plan.queryJobStreamInPlan(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiEngine(), "current", body, null, null);
        System.out.println("SIZE: "+jobStreamInPlanList.size());
        String jobStreamId="";
        for(JobStreamInPlan jobStream : jobStreamInPlanList) {
            if(jobStream.getTimeRestriction().getStartTime().equals(offsetDateTime)) {
                jobStreamId = jobStream.getId();
            }
        }

        if(jobStreamId!="") {
            logger.info("JobStream on TWS founded!");
            logger.info("Set JobStream with [Name]:[" + record.getJobStreamName() + "] and [Timestamp]: [" + offsetDateTime.toString() + "] to WAITING on TWS!");
            plan.setToWaitJobStreamInstance(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiEngine(), jobStreamId, "current", null);
        } else {
            logger.info("JobStream on TWS not founded!");
            logger.info("Scheduling JobStream with [Name]:[" + record.getJobStreamName() +"] and [Timestamp]: [" + offsetDateTime.toString() + "] on TWS!");
            plan.addJobStreamInstance(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiEngine(), "current", submitJobStreamInfo, null);
        }

    }

}
```

And then i need to cover with JUnit test the method addSchedulingOnTws(TwsRequest record). I wrote this test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TwsConnector.class, ApiClient.class, PlanApi.class})
public class TwsConnectorTest {

    
    @Mock
    private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;
    
    @Mock
    private ApiClient mockedApiClient;
    
    @Mock
    private PlanApi mockedPlanApi;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private TwsConnector twsConnector;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.when(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiUrl()).thenReturn("https://example.com/");
        PowerMockito.when(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiUsername()).thenReturn("MockedUser");
        PowerMockito.when(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiPassword()).thenReturn("MockedPassword");
        PowerMockito.when(propertiesConfig.getTwsApiEngine()).thenReturn("MockedEngine");   
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddSchedulingOnTws() throws Exception {


        Timestamp tms = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getYear(), 
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getMonthValue(),
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getDayOfMonth(),
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getHour(),
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getMinute(),
                tms.toLocalDateTime().getSecond(),
                0,
                ZoneOffset.UTC
                );
        
        List<JobStreamInPlan> mockedJobStreamInPlanList = new ArrayList<>();
        JobStreamInPlan mockedjobStreamInPlan = new JobStreamInPlan();
        JobStreamInPlanKey mockedKey = new JobStreamInPlanKey();
        mockedKey.setName("mocked");
        mockedjobStreamInPlan.setKey(mockedKey);
        TimeRestrictionsInPlan timeRestrictionsInPlan = new TimeRestrictionsInPlan();
        timeRestrictionsInPlan.setStartTime(offsetDateTime);
        mockedjobStreamInPlan.setTimeRestriction(timeRestrictionsInPlan);
        mockedJobStreamInPlanList.add(mockedjobStreamInPlan);
        
        PowerMockito.whenNew(PlanApi.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(ApiClient.class)).thenReturn(mockedPlanApi);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedPlanApi.queryJobStreamInPlan(anyString(), anyString(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mockedJobStreamInPlanList);


        TwsRequest twsRequest = new TwsRequest();
        twsRequest.setJobStreamName("mocked");
        twsRequest.setTsOperation(tms);
        
        twsConnector.addSchedulingOnTws(twsRequest);

    }
    
}
```

The test is obviously not complete yet but I would like to start testing the first part of the code.

The problem is that despite me adding:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(PlanApi.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(ApiClient.class)).thenReturn(mockedPlanApi);
PowerMockito.when(mockedPlanApi.queryJobStreamInPlan(anyString(), anyString(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mockedJobStreamInPlanList);
```

During the execution of the test a new object of type ApiClient is instantiated and in return a new object of PlanApi. Therefore, when the "queryJobStreamInPlan" method is called, the set mock is not received and a real connection attempt is made which obviously fails.

Can anyone point me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you can't compare Strings like this: if(jobStreamId!="")  (or at least not without expecting errors), there's a start

Comment: as for your mocks, they won't work because you declare and initialize those services/api's/... in the method itself.

Comment: A general rule of thumb if you need stuff like PowerMock(ito) you are doing it wrong. I would strongly suggest to instead of injecting the `PropertiesConfig` to instead inject the `PlanApi` as a dependency. Create an `@Configuration` with `@Bean` methods that create the needed beans and inject them. It will make your test (and eventually your life) a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. The problem here is that it's not really up to me to modify the existing code of the TwsConnector class (although all your observations are correct). The only thing "I was allowed" is to act on the test class so that the method is covered by the Junit test. Am I inferring that it is not possible to rewrite the test to have the method covered? Is a refactor of the TwsConnector class necessary?

Comment: you can't mock those service calls the way the code is now. If it's not up to you or if you're not allowed to modify the TwsConnector class, you shouldn't be writing the tests for it, neither. What were you supposed to do if the tests fail? Obviously, you wouldn't be allowed to correct any issues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of **Stultusque** and **M. Deinum** I proposed to change the implementation of the class. Effectively outsourcing the creation of the ApiClient and PlanApi objects by then injecting the PlanApi instance into the TwsConnector. This actually made testing the TwsConnector class much easier (it didn't even require the use of PowerMockito). Thank you both very much.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).